# How to make the element `display: none` by clicking the button

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to implement a function to hide elements when button is clicked in an application built using Angular 2.

```
<div *ngFor="let todo of todos" class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
  <div class="panel panel-default step"> // from here
      <div class="panel-body">
        <a [routerLink]="['/todo', todo.id]">{{todo.title}}</a>
        <button (click)="delete(todo.id)" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-circle pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></button>
      </div>
  </div>//so far
</div>
```

I want to know how to make the todo disappear when the button is clicked with the above code.
Although it is an elementary question, please teach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be removing that todo item as below

```
delete(id:number){
    this.todos.splice(id,1)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is not the right way to 'remove' an element on a todo list. @Aravind answer is better for it.

But if you really want to use `display:none`, you can do this like :

https://plnkr.co/edit/eXwAWWeH9N6REsqpzFCq?p=preview

```
<element ng-style="displayStyle"></element>
<button value="displayNone" ng-click="displayStyle={'display':'none'}">Display none</button>
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed you were searching for Angular 2. You can adapt it : `ng-click` => `(click)`. `ng-click` => `[ngStyle]`

Answer (score 2):

Small changes to Aravinds answer, since we need to find the index of the `todo`, so that right `todo` will be deleted

I like to pass the object in delete:

```
(click)="delete(todo)"
```

Need to find the index of the `todo` and then `splice`.

```
delete(todo) {
  this.todos.splice(this.todos.indexOf(todo),1);
}
```

---

### Update:

Just realized that it seems that you only want to **hide** the todo, and not delete it entirely. Well this can be achieved with the following. Upon initialization all todo's are visible. We could introduce a new variable to todo, when we want to hide it. So initially this property doesn't exist, so we mark inside the iteration: `*ngIf="!todo.hidden"`, complete code:

```
<div *ngFor="let todo of todos">
  <div class="panel-body" *ngIf="!todo.hidden">{{todo.name}}
    <button (click)="hide(todo)" type="button">Hide Todo</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the hide function sets the `hidden` property as true:

```
hide(todo) {
  todo.hidden = true;
}
```

This doesn't obviously give the option to actually unhide the todo, but that was not mentioned in your question.